# MySQL Query: Counting "Date" records in a table, with a "Date" less than the current record

Tags: mysql, count

I'm having trouble with a query that will ultimately let me count resale rate for some of my clients.

I'm trying to count clients that are repeat business every month and new business. In order to do this, I need to count these clients to see if they exist in the query with date that is less than the date in the current record.

Here's an extremely watered down version of what I need:

```
Date        Client  Count_Previous  
1/1/2014    abc                  0  
1/1/2014    def                  0  
1/1/2014    ghi                  0  
2/1/2014    abc                  1  
2/1/2014    def                  1  
2/1/2014    xyz                  0
```

So the query needs to search for `ABC` where `Date` is less than, in this example, #2/1/2014#.

The idea, being, however, is that as more months populate, the numbers subsequently change:

```
Date        Client  Count_Previous  
1/1/2014    abc                  0  
1/1/2014    def                  0  
1/1/2014    ghi                  0  
2/1/2014    abc                  1  
2/1/2014    def                  1  
2/1/2014    xyz                  0  
3/1/2014    mno                  0  
3/1/2014    def                  2  
3/1/2014    xyz                  1
```

Comment: I'm mysql. I have no idea what a "1/1/2014" is. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. I was able to get the results you're wanting with my test table.

```
SELECT  Date as myDate, Client as myClient, (select count(Client) FROM myTable 
WHERE Client = myClient and Date < myDate) as count_previous
FROM myTable
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5222f/1)

Comment: Hm I haven't tried that yet, but one of my issues was calling a nested select statement and making a comparison to the main select, i.e the "Date < myDate", where the nested select didn't know what I meant by "myDate".

Comment: You need to make sure your dates are in the correct format to be able to compare them. Instead of '1/1/2014' it needs to be '2014-01-01'. I added a fiddle link to my answer above.